# SSRS Font Color Using Wildcard parameter

Tags: reporting-services

Hi I have a report that i used a wild card search parameter so that i can pull record that contains a certain text.

For example: I need to search for subscription for Mary Johnson so on the keyword search box i just type "John". This set-up is working fine, but now I need to color that search keyword when found for each row. so i need assistance on expression code that mimics SQL syntax of LIKE in SSRS expression. I started to change the font color with `=iif(Instr(Fields!ReportRecipients.Value)=Parameters!Keyword.Value,"Maroon","Black")`, but it didnt work.

Please advise.

[image]

Sample

TOJo.eger@m.com; ruth.tuker@m.com;sandrae.espe@m.com; dan.gay@m.comIncludeReportTrueRenderFormatPDFSubjectDaily Report for IBC Medicare? was executed at @ExecutionTimeIncludeLinkFalsePriorityHIGH"

Answer (score 0):

You can use some .net string functions directly in SSRS expressions. In your case you can use the Contains() function like this.

```
=IIF(
    Fields!ReportRecipients.Value.Contains(Parameters!Keyword.Value), 
    "Maroon", 
    "Black"
    )
```

If you are dealing with HTML and only want the search term to be highlighted then you can simply use this as the `Value` expression. You must leave the text box color properties as default.

```
=REPLACE(
        Fields!ReportRecipients.Value, 
        Parameters!Keyword.Value,
        "<span style=""color:red;"">" & Parameters!Keyword.Value & "</span>"
        )
```

Finally, right-click the placeholder, choose properties and select Mark-up type as HTML

[image]

[image]

In this example, I used a country list and searched for the word "land", here's the results. The first column just uses the first method I described. The second column adds HTML tags.

[image]

Comment: "Contains" syntax is not available option after the Value. I doing the expression in Font color by the way.

Comment: Intellisense will not list it as a method but it will work. I have done exactly this in the past, using the above expression n the font color property.

Comment: So it is highlighting the entire field value instead of the keyword search value/  The value for the ReportRecipient is in a HTML tag format by the way.

Comment: This was not clear in your question. I will update the answer

Comment: Apologies. I thought the code would apply in general no matter what the data format is.

Comment: No problem, hopefully the updated answer will give you what you need.

Comment: The code is not functioning correctly. I added a sample of what i am trying to achieve (highlighted in yellow) wild card search.

Comment: Can you add some sample data as text, 1 record per line. Just a few records will do, then an example of the text you want to pass as a parameter. The code I posted works perfectly in the context I gave  as you can see from the example output. The problem might be that you are using XML tags, again this was not made clear in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219635/discussion-between-arsee-and-alan-schofield).

Comment: Sorry, no time. It's 9pm here and I'm still working. If you add the details I asked for myself or somebody will respond I'm sure

Comment: It won't accept XML tags .. hmm maybe i can change the Markup type to HTM then apply  the expression code with the XML tags?